Use interpolated values to fill missing rows in a column
I have per ID monthly cumulative counters, where in some months the counters are missing. I would like to replace these null entries with values interpolated between the nearest preceding and the closest following non-empty row.
My table looks like this:



ID
Month
Counter




AAA
2023-09
1000


AAA
2023-10
-


AAA
2023-11
-


AAA
2023-12
4000


BBB
2022-11
2000


BBB
2022-12
-


BBB
2023-01
-


BBB
2023-02
-


BBB
2023-03
4000



What I would like to have:



ID
Month
Counter




AAA
2023-09
1000


AAA
2023-10
2000


AAA
2023-11
3000


AAA
2023-12
4000


BBB
2022-11
2000


BBB
2022-12
2500


BBB
2023-01
3000


BBB
2023-02
3500


BBB
2023-03
4000



How can this be done in PostgreSQL?

In addition to the presenting the destired results, it would be very helpful to proviide the details of how the missing values were calculated. The title says "avarage values" but the missing counter values appear to be calculated as the last known counter plus the average monthly sales rate needed to get to the next known counter. There was also an apparent typo in some of the month values: I edited the post to correct those.

Your sample values make it seem like the first and last counter per ID are present, while the rest in between is null. But the explanation mentions nothing of the sort. Please clarify your case, disclose your version of Postgres, and show the exact (relevant parts of the ) table definition as CREATE TABLE script.

I think the word you were looking for is interpolated, not average. @Edouard's method below seems pretty efficient for that, assuming  first/last values for each id are always available. If you have more than one gap in the data for each id, that solution won't work, because you'd need to spot the closest preceding and following non-empties, not just the first/last value. If some ids can have empty leading/starting as well as trailing/ending/most recent rows, you'd probably want to also extrapolate backward/forward, not just interpolate

You can typically use window functions in order to calculate the missing values of Counter like in the following query :
SELECT id
     , month
     , counter
     , first_value(counter) OVER w
      + percent_rank() OVER w
      * ( last_value(counter) OVER w - first_value(counter) OVER w) AS new_counter
  FROM test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
 ORDER BY id, month

Result :



id
month
counter
new_counter




AAA
2023-09-01
1000
1000


AAA
2023-10-01
null
2000


AAA
2023-11-01
null
3000


AAA
2023-12-01
4000
4000


BBB
2022-11-01
2000
2000


BBB
2022-12-01
null
2500


BBB
2023-01-01
null
3000


BBB
2023-02-01
null
3500


BBB
2023-03-01
4000
4000



Then you can use this query in an UPDATE function if you want to update your table :
With query AS
( SELECT id
     , month
     , first_value(counter) OVER w
      + percent_rank() OVER w
      * ( last_value(counter) OVER w - first_value(counter) OVER w) AS new_counter
  FROM test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
UPDATE test AS t
   SET counter = q.new_counter
  FROM query AS q
 WHERE t.id = q.id
   AND t.month = q.month
   AND counter IS null ;

see the demo in dbfiddle
